# Mockito return value based on property of a parameter

Tags: java, mockito

Normally when using Mockito I will do something like:

```
Mockito.when(myObject.myFunction(myParameter)).thenReturn(myResult);
```

Is it possible to do something along the lines of

```
myParameter.setProperty("value");
Mockito.when(myObject.myFunction(myParameter)).thenReturn("myResult");

myParameter.setProperty("otherValue");
Mockito.when(myObject.myFunction(myParameter)).thenReturn("otherResult");
```

So rather than when just using the parameter to determine the result. It is using a value of a property inside the parameter to determine the result.

So when the code is executed it behaves like so:

```
public void myTestMethod(MyParameter myParameter,MyObject myObject){
    myParameter.setProperty("value");
    System.out.println(myObject.myFunction(myParameter));// outputs myResult

    myParameter.setProperty("otherValue");
    System.out.println(myObject.myFunction(myParameter));// outputs otherResult
}
```

---

Here is the current solution, hopefully something better can be suggested.

```
private class MyObjectMatcher extends ArgumentMatcher<MyObject> {

    private final String compareValue;

    public ApplicationContextMatcher(String compareValue) {
        this.compareValue= compareValue;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object argument) {
        MyObject item= (MyObject) argument;
        if(compareValue!= null){
            if (item != null) {
                return compareValue.equals(item.getMyParameter());
            }
        }else {
            return item == null || item.getMyParameter() == null;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public void initMock(MyObject myObject){
    MyObjectMatcher valueMatcher = new MyObjectMatcher("value");
    MyObjectMatcher otherValueMatcher = new MyObjectMatcher("otherValue");
    Mockito.when(myObject.myFunction(Matchers.argThat(valueMatcher))).thenReturn("myResult");
    Mockito.when(myObject.myFunction(Matchers.argThat(otherValueMatcher))).thenReturn("otherResult");
}
```

Comment: It's unclear from your question what is the object to be mocked and what is the object under test.

Comment: I have added an edit to demonstrate how I would like it to behave.

Comment: Any way I try to read this, it seems to me that you're mocking the object you want to test. And unless you have compelling reasons to do so and you're doing it in such a way that it doesn't impede the object's original behaviour, that defeats the purpose of testing in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, @ylabidi really has a point. What you want to do is possible, but it "feels" or "smells" a bit awkward. You should take a step back and ask if and why this is realy necessary. That is one of the reasons for testing: bad design usually leads to hard or awkward to test classes.

Comment: @ylabidi No I am not. The value of `myObject.myFunction(myParameter)` is being evaluated half way through the process I am testing and the expected result depends on the value it is returning. Normally the state of `myParameter` is not important to the result, so it is easy to do, however in this case the state of `myParameter` affects the end result making it more difficult.

Comment: @acdcjunior - using it to test a script in a foreign language that makes java calls, so yes it is a bit awkward.

Comment: If you want something better to be suggested, you shouldn't have accepted an answer.  Once you accept an answer, most people won't bother supplying a different one.  For what it's worth, I believe there is a better way of doing this - I might post an answer later.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it.  This uses an `Answer` object to check the value of the property.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTestClass {
    private String theProperty;
    @Mock private MyClass mockObject;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        when(mockObject.myMethod(anyString())).thenAnswer(
            new Answer<String>(){
            @Override
            public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation){
                if ("value".equals(theProperty)){
                    return "result";
                }
                else if("otherValue".equals(theProperty)) {
                    return "otherResult";
                }
                return theProperty;
            }});
    }
}
```

There's an alternative syntax, which I actually prefer, which will achieve exactly the same thing.  Over to you which one of these you choose.  This is just the `setUp` method - the rest of the test class should be the same as above.

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    doAnswer(new Answer<String>(){
        @Override
        public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation){
            if ("value".equals(theProperty)){
                return "result";
            }
            else if("otherValue".equals(theProperty)) {
                return "otherResult";
            }
            return theProperty;
        }}).when(mockObject).myMethod(anyString());
}
```

Comment: The solution you gave doesn't allow the mock the response based on different arguments of the mocked method. In this case, if we want to return a different response based on argument of mockObject.myMethod(String argument); if during run-time of test, if "argument" is "value" then return this and if "argument" is "othervalue" then return something else.

Comment: To get the argument, you can do something like `Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
      return (String) args[0];`

Answer (score 131):

In Java 8 it is even simpler than all of the above:

```
when(mockObject.myMethod(anyString()))
    .thenAnswer(invocation -> 
        invocation.getArgumentAt(0, String.class));
```

Comment: I like the idea of this but it seems incomplete? how does this differentiate between "value" and "otherValue" and return different answers in each case?

Comment: You can differentiate on different parameters by making the lambda bigger. Just add a if to it to select the write. It can be like this: `invocation-> { String param = invocation.getArgumentAt(0, String.class); if (param.equals("value")) return "myResultOnValue"; if (param.equals("otherParam") return "myResultOnOtherValue" else return "MyDefaultResult";`

Comment: No need to define type anymore. This is easier:
when(mockObject.myMethod (anyString() ) ).thenAnswer(invocation -> invocation.getArgument(0));

Comment: Sven and @MartijnHiemstra, your answers were very helpful to me. Thank you! I wasn't sure whether to edit this answer or create a new one. Feel free to copy anything useful from mine into yours, Sven, and I can delete mine. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64880543/631051

Comment: Nice concise update @Sven! FYI the method was `getArgument` for me, not `getArgumentAt`... Not sure why.

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can, using a custom argument matcher.

See [the javadoc of `Matchers`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Matchers.html) for more details, and more specifically [`ArgumentMatcher`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html).

Comment: I could use it in "when" method. Mockito.argThat returns null, thus causing exception.

Comment: @TT. Someone fixed the links. I further updated them to always point to the latest version.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how it would look like in Kotlin with [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/) library.

```
mock<Resources> {
    on {
        mockObject.myMethod(any())
    } doAnswer {
        "Here is the value: ${it.arguments[0]}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to do with with MockK?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with Mockito 3.6.0:

```
when(mockObject.myMethod(anyString()))
    .thenAnswer(invocation -> myStringMethod(invocation.getArgument(0)));
```

This answer is based on [Sven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41328274/631051) and Martijn Hiemstra's comment, with `getArgumentAt()` changed to `getArgument()`.

Comment: In Mockito 3.6.0, you can also do this:


    when(mockObject.myMethod(anyString()))
        .thenAnswer(AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg());