# How do I get Mockito to return different values based on an enum?

Tags: java, mockito

So I am trying to mock a method `getPremium` that takes a single parameter, an instance of `PanicLevel` which is an `enum`. It needs to return a different double value depending on the `PanicLevel` passed in.

If I want to do this per enum value then something like thi should work.

```
Mockito.when(mockData.getPremium(PanicLevel.NORMAL)).thenReturn(1.1);
```

But that needs a line per enum value. I'd much rather do something like:

```
Mockito.when(mockData.getPremium(anyPanicLevel())).thenReturn(premiums.get(passedInPanicLevel());
```

Obviously this isn't valid...but something similar should be....

I found this but it uses a method `anyString` from somewhere:
[mockito return value based on property of a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22338536/mockito-return-value-based-on-property-of-a-parameter)

How do I get Mockito to do this without doing repeated `when` for each key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an `Answer`:

```
Mockito.when(mockData.getPremium(Matchers.any(PanicLevel.class)))
    .thenAnswer(new Answer<Double>() {
        @Override
        public Double answer(InvocationOnMock arg0) throws Throwable {
          PanelLevel panicLevel = (PanicLevel) arg0.getArguments()[0];
          return premiums.get(panicLevel);
        }        
    });
```

FYI: `anyString()` is likely just `Matchers.anyString()`.

Comment: Technically the cast is not safe because `any` really accepts any objects but oh well...

Comment: I guess then that you could avoid an unsafe cast using `return premiums.get(arg0.getArguments()[0]);`.

Answer (score 0):

Output is dependent on the PanicLevel enum value. Then we need to mock all values that are required for test case.  I don't think there is any other way of doing. You can have Properties(enumValue, ouput) then iterate them to achieve this.

Comment: See andy's answer, it is possible :)

Answer (score -1):

[Mockito: How to match any enum parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19949762/mockito-how-to-match-any-enum-parameter)

Looks like you will need to use Matchers.any(Class)

```
Mockito.when(mockData.getPremium(Matchers.any(PanicLevel.class)).thenReturn(premiums.get(passedInPanicLevel());
```

Comment: But what about `passedInPanicLevel()`?